is there any possible ways CustomMultiChildLayout can not take height?
For what reasons can CustomMultiChildLayout give an infinite height error? Shouldn't it dynamically adjust to the height of the elements? I have a column inside which CustomMultiChildLayout is and there are chips inside it, but it can’t draw the chips because the height gives an infinite error. The point is that I don’t need to hardcode the height of the sized box that lies inside because the height can be dynamic due to the length of the text, for example
Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
           CustomMultiChildLayout(
                  delegate: WrapLayoutDelegate(widget.items.length),
                  children: <Widget>[
                
                    for (int i = 0; i < widget.items.length; i++)
                      LayoutId(
                        id: i,
                        child:  CustomChipButton(
                            title: widget.items[i].name,
                            colorHex: widget.items[i].icon.isNotEmpty ? widget.items[i].icon : null,
                            isSelected: widget.isSelected(widget.items[i]),
                            onTap: () => widget.onItemTap(widget.items[i]),
                          ),
                        ),

                  ],
                );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

class WrapLayoutDelegate extends MultiChildLayoutDelegate {
  WrapLayoutDelegate(this.childCount, {this.horizontalSpacing = 8.0, this.verticalSpacing = 8.0});

  final int childCount;
  final double horizontalSpacing;
  final double verticalSpacing;

  static const int _maxRow = 2;

  @override
  void performLayout(Size size) {
    double totalWidth = 0;
    double rowHeight = 0;
    double maxRowHeight = 0;
    double currentRowNumber = 1;

    bool isOverload() => currentRowNumber > _maxRow;

    final Size titleSize = layoutChild('Title', BoxConstraints.loose(size));
    rowHeight += titleSize.height;
    positionChild('Title', const Offset(0, 0));

    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
      final Size childSize = layoutChild(i, BoxConstraints.loose(size));
      if (isOverload()) {
        layoutChild(i,BoxConstraints.loose(size));
        positionChild(i, Offset(-childSize.width, -childSize.height));
        continue;
      }

      if (hasChild(i)) {
        final double adjustedTotalWidth = totalWidth > 0 ? totalWidth + horizontalSpacing : totalWidth;
        final double newTotalWidth = adjustedTotalWidth + childSize.width;
        maxRowHeight = max(childSize.height, maxRowHeight);

        if (newTotalWidth > size.width) {
          currentRowNumber++;
          if (isOverload()) {
            positionChild(i, Offset(-childSize.width, -childSize.height));
            continue;
          }
          totalWidth = childSize.width;
          positionChild(i, Offset(0, rowHeight + maxRowHeight + verticalSpacing));
          rowHeight += maxRowHeight + verticalSpacing;
          maxRowHeight = 0;
        } else {
          positionChild(i, Offset(adjustedTotalWidth, rowHeight));
          totalWidth = newTotalWidth;
        }
      }
    }

    final Size moreSize = layoutChild('More', BoxConstraints.loose(size);
    if (isOverload()) {
      positionChild('More', Offset(size.width - moreSize.width, 0));
    } else {
      positionChild('More', Offset(-moreSize.width - 20, -moreSize.height));
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRelayout(covariant MultiChildLayoutDelegate oldDelegate) => false;
}


"Shouldn't it dynamically adjust to the height of the elements?" no, CustomMultiChildLayout cannot size itself based on the size of it's children

@pskink so basically until I set the height of the container that contains CustomMultichildLayout, will I get an error about infinite height?

basically getSize should return a finite size, by default it is implemented as Size getSize(BoxConstraints constraints) => constraints.biggest; and in your case constraints.biggest seems to be Size.infinite or something like that - override WrapLayoutDelegate.getSize and check what is returned by super.getSize()
